# How can I get just the URL from this?

Tags: php, html

I get a lot of **DMCA** removal emails for my website, and I'm trying to automate the process of removing those tracks from my website.

The emails all come looking similar to this.

```
http://example.com/title-to-post.html title - to post
http://example.com/title-of-post.html title - of post
http://example.com/some-song-artist-some-song-name.html some song artist - some song name
```

But there's a lot of them, I only wanna return the URL portion of every part of this, example being below.

```
http://example.com/title-to-post.html
http://example.com/title-of-post.html
http://example.com/some-song-artist-some-song-name.html
```

**EDIT:** I am storing these files into a txt file, then calling them using standard code.

```
$urls = file_get_contents( "oururls.txt" );
$data = explode(",", $urls);
    foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "$item";
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Nothing really fancy going on, how ever it's returning the title also and I want just the ***urls***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's always a space after the URL you can explode the text by " " and get the first portion. Example:

```
$example = explode(" ", $url);
echo $example[0];
```